# Jquery: Triggering not working?

Tags: jquery

```
$("body").on("triggerMe", function(){
    alert("Hey, I've been triggered!");
});

$(function(){
    $("body").trigger("triggerMe");
});
```

How come the function attached to the "triggerMe" event is not called when it's triggered?

Comment: It works...http://jsfiddle.net/X58BW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely calling it in head...before body exists. Put on() inside ready:

```
    $(function(){

        $("body").on("triggerMe", function(){
            alert("Hey, I've been triggered!");
        });     

        $("body").trigger("triggerMe");
    });
```

Or bind to document outside ready()

```
   $(document).on("triggerMe", function(){
        alert("Hey, I've been triggered!");
    });

    $(function(){  

        $(document).trigger("triggerMe");
    });
```

Will work in a fiddle due to load settings preconfigured

Comment: That's a good idea to call your JQuery code on the document's ready event when there's no reason to do it before.